# Adding buttons next to TextField on Form

Tags: qooxdoo

I am new to QOOXDOO (like really new). I am enjoying the framework tremendously though, and am busy with a feasibility test for a desktop like app.

I have a straight forward enough Form using a single column render, having test data TextFields like "Account number", "Name", "Cell number". That is working well of course. But I need two small pick list type buttons next to the "Account number" TextField. One for searching by account number, and one for searching by name.

I really don't see how to achieve the positioning of these two buttons?

I am using 5.01 of the framework, but can of course change to 6 if it has a good way of achieving those two pick list buttons I need.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Maybe a custom widget would do?

Comment: Thanks Voger! I played around with a custom widget for a while, but I couldn't find a way to add it to a form.

Comment: In the end, I decided to skip the form interface, and rather manually place the widgets. It's a lot more work than I had hoped, but that is my best solution for the moment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
var doc = this.getRoot();

var form = new qx.ui.form.Form();

var txt1 = new qx.ui.form.TextField("");
form.add(txt1, "Account number", null, "account_number");

var txt2 = new qx.ui.form.TextField("");
form.add(txt2, "Name", null, "name");

var txt3 = new qx.ui.form.TextField("");
form.add(txt3, "Cell number", null, "cell_number");


var s1 = new qx.ui.form.SelectBox();
var s2 = new qx.ui.form.SelectBox();


var formView = new qx.ui.form.renderer.Single(form);

formView._add(s1, {row: 0, column: 2});
formView._add(s2, {row: 0, column: 3});

doc.add(formView, {left: 10, top: 10});
```